# How do I make jQuery JSON returned data available globally & Minor string parse help?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, getjson

I have made an API call with the help of `$.getJSON` but I don't know how do I make the returned data available globally to be used in other functions as well.

The `return` in below code doesn't work but instead if I `alert` it: it works charms.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(timeInfo){
        return timeInfo.time;
});
```

**Also out of 2010-12-09 12:53 time format. How do I take the 12 (the hour) out.**

Please help and sorry for including two questions in one.

Detailed code:

```
function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
    if(position[0] == 'Yes'){
        var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=" + position[1] + "&lng=" + position[2] + "&callback=?";
    } else {
        var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lng=" + position.coords.longitude + "&callback=?";
    }
    $.getJSON(url, function(weatherInfo){
        var clouds = weatherInfo.weatherObservation.clouds;
        var weather = weatherInfo.weatherObservation.weatherCondition;
        var time = getTimeInfo(position);
        if(time.getHours()>=6 && time.getHours()<=18){
            var weatherClass = placeImageDay(clouds, weather);
            $('#weatherImage').show().addClass(weatherClass);
        } else {
            var weatherClass = placeImageNight(clouds, weather);
            $('#weatherImage').show().addClass(weatherClass);
        }
    });
}

function getTimeInfo(position){
    if(position[0] == 'Yes'){
        var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=" + position[1] + "&lng=" + position[2] + "&callback=?";
    } else {
        var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lng=" + position.coords.longitude + "&callback=?";
    }
    $.getJSON(url, function(timeInfo){
        return timeInfo.time;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the data to other functions and objects from the success callback function in `$.getJSON()`. The way you do that is either create a global object or function:

```
var MYWEBSITE = { data: {} };
var myGlobalFunction = function(data) { 
  alert("The time I got is: " + data.time);
};

$.getJSON(url, function(timeInfo) {

  // set the data property on MYWEBSITE
  MYWEBSITE.data = timeInfo;

  // execute the function and pass the parameter
  myGlobalFunction(timeInfo);
});
```

**EDIT**: *Added example of passing global functions as second parameter*

You can also pass a global function as second parameter:

```
var globalFunction = function(data) { ... };

$.getJSON(url, globalFunction);
```

That way, `globalFunction` gets passed whatever is returned in the response.

**EDIT 2**: *Added regular expression example for time extraction*

To extract the hour portion of the date, you can use a Regex to match the components:

```
var time = "2010-12-09 12:53", hour = "";
var timeMatcher = /^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})$/;
if(timeMatcher.test(time)) {
  hour = timeMatcher.match(time)[2]; // finds the second brace, hour should contain "12"
}
```

For more info, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: I understand that callback is the way. But if you see my detailed code I have added above. I am using one function in another. Can you try to explain how do I manage to do your technique in my code. You don't need to write the code if you don't wish to, just try to throw the concept towards me. 

Thanks a lot

Comment: Like I said, replace `return timeInfo.time;` in your callback with the appropriate function call to pass `timeInfo` to the correct handler, exactly as you're already doing in the first callback function in your detailed code (calling `placeImageDay` and `placeImageNight`). You can also just put the name of the function into `$.getJSON()`. I've added the code as an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is asyncronous call and you cannot return a value like , it just instantiate the proces sand goes on , anything you want you have do inside return handler

```
   $.getJSON(url, function(timeInfo){
            processData(timeInfo)
    });

function processData(Info)
{
///do acess them here
}
```